# What is mean by Task timed out after 3.00 seconds - AWS Lambda with node.js, AWS RDS, AWS cloudwatch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am executing select query in aws lambda(nodejs) then i got this(Task timed out after 3.00 seconds ) message in aws cloudwatch.

Comment: Check the configuration for TimeOut in the Lambda. if you configure the Lambda function to run in VPC then check there also

Comment: ok thanks for the help